# Backbone templates views and js loading

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm facing a problem with the foundation's js instances, basically when I render a new view, it add news elements into the DOM and since the **foundation()** instanciation was already loaded, I need to instanciate again on the views.

Using underscore.js and backbone.js

I just wonder if I can just modify the _.template function to auto instanciate foundation instead of manually set the code on each view.

I'm adding this piece of script on everyview

```
 $(document).foundation();
```

Each time I execute _.template.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Seems a bit heavy handed to override _.template for this.  Also, if you ever do template caching (you should), this solution will stop working.  Call foundation from the render method of your views (where needed... I don't know anything about foundation but it seems crazy that you'd need to do $(document).foundation() for every DOM change)

Comment: lol for some reason I didn't think about call it on the render, that make the trick, however, it is still kind of crazy having to instanciate foundation() each time I call View's initialize/render method. I'm kind of sure it must be a better solution out there. Thanks for you help Robert.

Comment: yeah, probably worth opening a new question tagged for foundation (leaving out the backbone stuff) specifically about what you need to do when the DOM changes

Comment: @andresmijares25: There probably isn't a better solution than (maybe) `this.$el.foundation()`. In general there's no way to know when new things are added to the DOM so you have to do it yourself. jQuery-Mobile requires a similar dance. But `render` is the right place for this sort of thing.